# Can the Newsletter style of the standard view be modified?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, css

We're displaying a number of metadata fields in the newsletter style of the standard view.

```
+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Field1: Value          |Field2: Value                  |Field3: Value               |
+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+
Field4: Value


Freeform Text: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 


+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Next record                                                                         |
+------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I'd like to be able to force Field4 to display on the header line leaving the "body" portion of the record to just the freeform text portion. Anyone know a good client-side (e.g., no .NET development, minimal SPD) way to do this? I suspect there's a CSS I can modify somewhere, moving a `</div>` to AFTER Field 4, but I have no idea where to find that or where to put it once it's modified so that it gets picked up on the way to being displayed.

Tips or hints?

Comment: Has anyone been able to find how to edit the "newsletter, no lines" view in SP 2013? I cannot find the web part template to edit, and have been looking online most of the morning.

Comment: This appears to be getting me part of the way, will update when I find something more but at least now I can see the XSL:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b8e2f14-81ab-4d57-808b-d452001e0ccf/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on doing exactly this with DVWPs many moons ago, it may help...

http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/sharepoint-designer-dataview-web-parts.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the page in Sharepoint Designer and convert the view to a Dataview Web Part?

From there, you'd have full control over the XSLT and can rearrange the web part to get the desired affect.

Edit: Create a new view through the browser with the proper style applied.  Then go into the view in advanced mode in SharePoint Designer.  Click on the view and then in the ribbon, go to the Design tab of the List View Tools. Click the Customize XSLT button and select the Customize Entire View option.  Then you should be in business.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I've been finding SPD to be quite cumbersome, with a steep learning curve. :\ I'll hunt down some tutorials and see if I can make that work. Sounds like a good solution if I can... :)

Comment: It should just be a matter of adding an additional TD or div to the header and moving the field into it.

Comment: I've got the page open in SPD. I can find NOTHING to convert it to a dataview webpart. Is this something that may be disabled in Foundation? All the tutorials mention is that I should right click on "it" to convert "it"...without mentionins what the "it" actually is: a listing in a file manager, the code itself, some menu somewhere? I've not been able to fiund "it."

Comment: Edited with more information.